# how does u-boot maps peripheral memory?

Tags: u-boot

I am confused how the registers(for ex: for uart controller) are mapped in u-boot?
Are they memory mapped in DDR? If yes How?
If not then what is the meaning of "peripheral addresses are memory mapped" in U-Boot?

Comment: We need more context and information, can you tell us where you heard the phrase  "peripheral addresses are memory mapped" so we can explain what they meant by it in context with what was being talked about?

Comment: http://portinguboottoanewboard.blogspot.com/

Comment: I am sorry; if my question was not clear. I am referring to OMAP u-boot code. As if I want to configure the gpio; For ex: we just do (unsigned int *)0x48009876 = 0xff. I want to know how these operation is performed.

Comment: it should be `*((unsigned int *)0x48009876) = 0xff` note the asterisk in the beginning for de-referencing :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

The registers are mapped to <s>RAM</s> **memory address space** at hardware level using different type of interconnects in the SoC. e.g Lets take the example of OMAP 35x series and see how UART registers are mapped to the <s>RAM</s> memory address space of the SoC and how we may access them in U-Boot.

In the [Technical Reference Manual for OMAP 35x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruf98x/spruf98x.pdf), *Table 2-3. L4-Core Memory Space Mapping*, we see that base address for UART1 is `0x4806A000` and the size (of RAM that it occupies) is 4KB.

It means that registers for UART1 are mapped to <s>RAM</s> the memory space in a 4KB region starting at this address.

To access a register of UART1, we need to know its offset from the base address to get its actual address. These offsets can be found in *Table 17-39 UART IrDA CIR Register Summary*.

Once we know the actual address we make a pointer to that register using

```
unsigned int * (base_address + offset)
```

Once we have the pointer we can de-reference it to read/write the register. e.g

To read a register in a variable 'x' we use:

```
unsigned int x;
x = *(unsigned int * (base_address + offset));
```

Writing a register is also similar

```
*(unsigned int *(base_address + offset)) = some_value;
```

To get a better understanding of how memory mapping is implemented at hardware level, skim through the Chapter 2, 'Memory Mapping', of TRM.

Comment: *"the registers are mapped to RAM "* is incorrect.  *"RAM"* is not synonymous with "memory address space".

Comment: Thanks @sawdust answer updated with correct terminology in light of your comment